# Вызов консоли через код питон

Tags: python, консоль, pycharm, print

Нужно во время **работы программы** запустить **консоль**, к примеру для вывода оттуда какой-то инфы через **print()**. Другие варианты вывода не предлагать, нужна только консоль. К сожалению, информации никакой не нашёл. Если это имеет значение, работаю в в PyCharm.

Comment: Поясните, вам нужно запустить приложение "Консоль" или выполнить какую-то консольную команду? Приведите пример желаемого результата

Comment: По умолчанию любой python-код работает с консолью. Если после выполнения она у вас закрывается, это не означает, что она не открывалась вовсе. Попробуйте в конце своего кода добавить `input()` (сохранять в переменную его не надо)

Comment: хочу создать программу, которая будет в определённый момент просто  открывать консоль и выводить туда рандомные символы, закрываться, а потом снова тоже самое. не спрашивайте лучше, зачем такое надобно))